# Install nginx web server using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, nginx

I want to automate the installation of nginx web service in such a way that if nginx is already present it will get installed at other location ex: /usr/local/nginx.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Beginning installation of nginx web server"
if ! which nginx > /dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "Nginx is not installed"
else
    echo "Installing nginx"
    yum install nginx -y
    
    #check if nginx services are up
    service nginx start
fi
```

I am new to shell script and tried above approach, however I am unable to execute command in else block.
Help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Install nginx on your web-01 server
# Nginx should be listening on port 80
# When querying Nginx at its root / with a GET request
# (requesting a page) using curl, it must return a page
# that contains the string Hello World!

sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install nginx
echo 'Hello World' | sudo tee /var/www/html/index.html
sudo service nginx start
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what you wanted to do but logic in you code is not the best, so here is snip from one of my first bash scripts where i did something similar:

```
  read INP
  if [ $INP -eq 1 ]
  then
    if command -v nginx
    then
      systemctl status nginx
      back
    else
      error
      read INP
      if [ $INP == y ]
      then
        sudo apt install nginx
      else
        back
      fi
    fi
  fi
```

Btw this is for Debian based distros, so you can change apt for yum, pacman, etc. package manager. And just to be clear, back and error are functions i created.